Is there a way to optimize parameter substitution in an equation for faster computation in C++
I've a set of equations which take vector inputs and return solution for different time steps. There are a few parameters in the equations which are received during runtime and stay constant for that cycle. I want to replace such parameter with their values computed during runtime such that further computation uses equations with substituted value of parameter.The original problem has 4000 such parameters but I'm giving a sample equation to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.
A smaller example to illustrate the issue:
 rval[0]  = -p1*x + p2*y*z;
  rval[1]  = -rval[0] - p3*y*y - dy;
  rval[0] -=  dx;
  rval[2]  =  x + y + z - 1;


{p1,p2,p3} are fixed set of parameters whose value is received online and the new set of equations would essentially become
  rval[0]  = (-0.04)*x + (1.0e4)*y*z;
  rval[1]  = -rval[0] - (3.0e7)*y*y - dy;
  rval[0] -=  dx;
  rval[2]  =  x + y + z - 1;

One way I've tried is using symengine symbolic C++ library but it has increased overhead of substitution and computation using symengine equations
Code tried for the equations above with symengine library
// Create a map for substitution
SymEngine::map_basic_basic subs_map;
subs_map[x_sym] = real_double(x);
subs_map[y_sym] = real_double(y);
subs_map[z_sym] = real_double(z);
subs_map[dx_sym] = real_double(dx);
subs_map[dy_sym] = real_double(dy);
subs_map[dz_sym] = real_double(dz);

// Evaluate equations
rval[0] = SymEngine::eval_double(*resv1->subs(subs_map));
rval[1] = SymEngine::eval_double(*resv2->subs(subs_map));
rval[2] = SymEngine::eval_double(*resv3->subs(subs_map));

The equations resv1, resv2 and resv3 are same as equations mentioned above with substituted parameters
Is there an alternate way to achieve high speed for evaluating equations by substituting the parameters or is there a faster way to do this in symengine as well.
Note: Please note that I'm using a much large set of equations than this which runs for several iterations per time step but I'm experimenting with a smaller set of equations to check feasibility of the solution.

I'd expect the optimized program to keep the values for p1, p2 and p3 in registers (unless it runs out of registers). Have you checked the assembly?

I don't see the gain in shown example. I don't expect an improvement from p1*x to (-0.04)*x...  If you had to compute p1², then I might see the possible gain but then an extra variable might do the job...

You may want to delve into constexpr and consteval, but I'd expect that if you just enable your compilers Optimizer then that will probably be irrelevant. In any case, I'd expect negligible difference here. Why do you care?

I agree with @TedLyngmo any half decent optimising compiler will load parameters that remain constant over one iteration into registers outside of the loop provided that there are not too many of them. You will have to check the assembly code it generates to be sure. The other advice is run a profiler on the code execution to see where the time wasting hotspots really are. It is all too easy to obsess on one irrelevant detail when the bottleneck is elsewhere. Worth trying out the Intel ICX compiler if you care about speed - some of its tricks make a real difference.

Similar advice here: Write the simple easy to understand code, turn on your compilers optimizations, and then benchmark/profile the code.  If you are happy with the performance as is then job done.  If not, then you have data on where the slowness is coming from and you can tackle that directly instead of just guessing at what could make it faster.

I have not checked the assembly but in the original problem there are some 4000 parameters so I don't think registers would be sufficient

If this actually matters, use a code profiler, Intel Vtune or AMD equivalent, and measure where your actual bottle necks are. The code you present here is likely memory bandwidth limited rather than compute

The difference between 4 and 4000 parameters is a rather important detail that you omitted from your original question. Intel ICX & VTune and profile directed compilation is probably the way to go if you really need to make it go any faster. If you are lucky it might even vectorise some parts of the innermost code on the fly.

There is no (mainstream) hardware that can hold 4000 parameters in registers since the number of register is generally far smaller than that (and always bounded). Since each parameter is apparently a double-precision number, then it takes 32K in memory. This is about the size of the L1 cache on many CPU. If variables can stay in the L1, then they can be quickly loaded. Otherwise, there is an additional latency. In this case, reducing the number of parameter is the key. On mainstream x86-64 CPUs, a mul/add/fma with a constant are not faster than variable, but it may consume less µops.

If you can, the way to go is to evaluate the same expression with multiple (similar) inputs (i.e. arrays) so to benefit from SIMD instructions (same instructions applied on multiple data). The speed up can be massive on mainstream CPUs.

Also be aware that large codes can be slower to execute than small ones doing the same job, simply because instructions are stored in caches (µops cache, L1 instr cache, L2, etc.). A code such as the one you show with 4000 variables will typically not fit in the µops cache and maybe not even in the L1 cache too. As a result, your code can be bounded by cache miss and instruction decoding. You need to profile this with a low-level profiler to check that. In this case, it is better to split the code in parts, and reuse the same part for multiple inputs, before switching to a new part.

I recommend splitting up your program in multiple functions an try a pipelining approach.  For example, as soon as part 1 is finished, the output is forwarded to part 2 and a new input is given to part 1.  The objective is make the functionality small enough that each piece can be run by a single core.  You set up multiple cores and hopefully have these cores all running at the same time.

Don't use std::map or any container based on linked lists.  The nodes may be out of the processor's data cache range, thus wasting time reloading the data cache.  Arrays are better.  Arrays that can fit in a processor's data cache are better.  Array elements can usually be accessed with one instruction.  The std::map must search to find its elements.  By definition, an array's elements are sequential and can use math to find the elements.

Do you expect some of the variables to take "nice" values like 0 or ±1, i.e. values that actually allow simplifications in the formulas?

Using double p2 = 1.0e4 or the constant 1.0e4 really doesn't matter much to a floating point mathematics unit.  If you are using -ffast-math it can make some difference, as it lets the compiler reorder floating point expressions to not exactly match the IEEE required results, but instead generate equations that are algebraically equivalent.
See What does gcc's ffast-math actually do? for details on what -ffast-math does and alternatives.
Even with ffast-math, true constants (ie, recompile the program with the constants hard coded) might cause a significant rewrite in some cases (ie, it solves that your constants means some value is multiplied by 0, so it skips calculating that value), but short of that you aren't going to get much improvement.  Humans might get faster if asked to multiply by 3 times ten to the 7 a few million times in a row, but a FPU won't.  The millionths multiplication will be just as fast.
You can arrange your math to make FPUs faster, but that mainly involves making your math follow SIMD patterns, doing 4 or 8 or more parallel floating point operations per cycle; or in more extreme cases, arranging for your code to be run on a GPU (which can sort of work like a super-wide SIMD FPU, doing 100s of identical operations in parallel very cheaply).
None of these look like things that would magically happen after you "fixed some parameters".  They would require work on your part to get working.

Don't use -ffast-math. Telling people to use compiler options that can lead to incorrect results is a bad idea.

This is especially true since we do not know exactly what are the bottlenecks yet (likely caches and instruction decoding). If so, -ffast-math will certainly not make things faster while being dangerous.

Besides, GPU are great for massively parallel (SIMD) code and we do not know if it fits the OP needs. Not to mention GPUs only have a limited set of registers. Using a lot of them often makes GPU codes much much slower due to a very low occupancy (e.g. running 1 thread instead of 256 simultaneously wasting most GPU resources).

@JérômeRichard It is dangerous if people expect IEEE mathematics.  If people do not expect IEEE mathematics from their floating point values, what breaks?  I provided a link to an extensive list of what dangers there are with -ffast-math and what alternative flags you can use if something is a problem with those dangers.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont We don't know if the OP use inf, NaN or even subnormal numbers. In such case, -ffast-math can give completely wrong values (mathematically speaking -- not even close -- like 1 instead of Inf). Providing a link is good, but my main point is that we need to find the bottlenecks before applying solutions to different problems not fixing the OP one.

@JesperJuhl using -ffastmath always has to be a value judgement. Sometimes the speed up gain can be significant and worth the usually small risk of bad behaviour (you have to regression test it against a reference normal code). Just one GCC default fastmath behaviour I really dislike is that it will optimise an explicit test for isnan to never fail (ie the conditional test is replaced by the code executed for false) and that is distinctly antisocial. None of the other major compilers I have used do that when go-faster stripes are enabled.

@JérômeRichard I found with GCC it was more a problem of -ffastmath giving a result of Nan where other mainstream compilers returned a perfectly sensible value (even with risky FP optimisations enabled). Ignoring explicit tests for isnan is unforgivable. I know how to work around it now but it caught me by surprise the first time I saw it.

If the parameters are truly computed/collected at runtime, then having them in variables is sufficient. There are ways to hint that a variable doesn't change much, but if you make a point of declaring/calculating those variables outside the loop of the equations, then the compiler will do right thing. (It won't load the variable from memory when it already has it). Often it can even detect that a computation is not dependent on the loop state and will move it out of the loop as part of its own internal optimization. (meaning you might not notice a performance boost when you make this change yourself)
Now if there genuinely are 4000 'p's. You want to organize your loops so that it can process over everything that uses p[1] and p[2]... if you loop over too many 'p's at once, then there will be a lot more memory accesses.
Also if you group all the p[1] stuff ahead of the p[2] stuff, then you increase the likelihood that the value can stay in a register. The theme is to not introduce new stuff until you are done with the old stuff if you can avoid it. (In small enough chunks, the optimizer has a chance of doing this for you, and you might not notice a speedup in that chunk)
Pulling repeated computations outside the body of the loop is a code optimization.
The rest is optimization for cache misses (which can result in things being tracked in registers.
If they are merely reading in a file with 4000 parameters that change rarely (you can tolerate rebuilding the executable between changes), Then you could consider putting them in a header file as a const static double p[].
I assume you are writing loops and this might not gain you anything.
But it will do the substitution at compile time and optimize as constants when it can. If you just have 4000 hardcoded indexes/names in your equations, then this will indeed get you some pretty good optimization. This smells funny though and there might be a better design to your software (out of scope of the question).
- Out of scope of 'parameter substitution optimization': If you are solving many repeated things similar to your example, looking at Cuda/GPU to do it massively in parallel might be attractive.

Applying p1 to all inputs first, then p2, then p3 can be a speedup to prevent the parameters from register spilling. But this replaces one problem with another: now your inputs and outputs might spill.
